# How to extend a class

Tags: objective-c

I have a class called `VideoListViewController`, which is an abstract class (i.e. only meant for subclassing). Now I want to extend this in `ShareViewController` and `MyVideosViewController`. For example, in Python that would be

```
class VideoListViewController (UIViewController):
    # implementation

class ShareViewController (VideoListViewController):
    # implementation

class MyVideosViewController (VideoListViewController):
    # implementation
```

What I have is:

```
// VideoListViewController.h

@interface VideoListViewController : UIViewController
// interface declaration
@end


// ShareViewController.h

#import "VideoListViewController.h"
@interface ShareViewController : VideoListViewController   
                                // ^ this line shows an error
// interface declaration
@end
```

But this does not compile (`Cannot find interface declaration for 'VideoListViewController', superclass of 'ShareViewController'`).

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted here. No other errors?

Comment: @JoshCaswell This is the only error I get, and `VideoListViewController` seems to be imported when declaring `ShareViewController`, because XCode autocompletes the name for me

Comment: Tried whacking it with your fist^W^W^W^W^W cleaning the project (⇧-⌘-K)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell cleaning the project didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the "VideoListViewController" class is not compiled and has errors in itself and hence cannot be extended by another class. Try the following -

1. Try clean build.
2. Try importing "<UIKit/UIKit.h>" in VideoListViewController.h since it extends UIViewController? as in -

// VideoListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VideoListViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

3. Check if "VideoListViewController.m" is included in the target membership. To check this select the VideoListViewController.m file in the navigator and open file inspector. Under "Target Membership" the target you are building for should be checked. If not check it. You might have forgotten this while creating the file where this option is provided.

4.It could be a problem of circular reference. Make sure you do not have any header files of sub class in super class. Like #import ShareViewController.h in VideoListViewController.h. Also relook at any @class references if you have.

Comment: I'm importing UIKit (the code was stripped down for readability). Is it possible that the `VideoListViewController.h` has compilation errors but doesn't show them?

Comment: Updated the answer with third option of possible "Target Membership" issue. Please check.

Comment: It could be a problem of circular reference. Make sure you do not have any header files of sub class in super class. Like **#import ShareViewController.h** in **VideoListViewController.h**. Also relook at any @class references if you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing the designated initializer (init method) inside `VideoListViewController` and returning `nil` from that. Then it will become an abstract class.